# How to display all images from a media library on Windows Phone 8?

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have tried the following code, but it has not resulted in any activity on Windows Phone 8:

```
MediaLibrary m = new MediaLibrary();

foreach (var r in m.Pictures)
{
    Stream imageStream = r.GetImage();

    var imageToShow = new Image()
    {
        Source = PictureDecoder.DecodeJpeg(r.GetImage())
    };

    lstImageFromMediaLibrary.Items.Add(imageToShow);
}
```

Comment: I have edited your question.  There was an extra closing brace in your code which I removed.  Please check and make sure my edit is correct.

Comment: Is your app registered as a handler for the image files? (.jpg, .png, ..) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206987(v=vs.105).aspx#BKMK_Fileassociations

Comment: Thank Adam very much!i did.